# Change bcrypt.compareSync to async if better

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

Here my authentication process:

**Session > Controller.js**

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const repository = require("./repository");

const config = require("../../config");
const logger = require("../../utilities/logger");

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.body.password || !req.body.username) {
        res.preconditionFailed("Credentials required");
        return;
    }

    try {
        const user = await repository.findUser(req.body);
        if (!user || !user.comparePasswords(req.body.password)) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: "Authentication failed." });
            return;
        }

        const token = jwt.sign(user.toObject(), config.secret, { expiresIn: 1440 });
        logger.info("User loged in with success. Login token", token);
        res.json({
            success: true,
            token,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
};
```

**User > Model.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: String, required: true },
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        // hash the password using our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});

userSchema.methods.comparePasswords = function(candidatePassword) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(candidatePassword, this.password);
};

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

In the user model, I'm using the bcrypt method `compareSync`. It's recommended to use the async method `compare` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

Could someone explain why? And what would be a good implementation? It's working well like that but I would like to be sure I'm using the best practices.

Answer (score 1):

`compareSync` is extremely CPU intensive task. Since Node.js Event Loop is single threaded, you block entire application unless you comparison got finished.

Main rule using node.js is to always avoid synchronous code execution.
Reason is `event-driven` nature of framework.

Good & detailed explanation can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/)